# Parse with Facebook Login not working

Tags: ios, xcode, facebook, authentication, parse-platform

So I am using the Parse SDK and also the Facebook SDK. For my app I would like to be able to sign out and sign in with the Facebook login button(also have an email sign in). I currently am able to sign in if the user is logged in to Facebook from within the settings or the Facebook, they have no problem signing at all. When the user tries to sign in but they do not have the Facebook installed and they aren't signed in in the settings, it redirects to safari and it'll go back to the app but it won't segue its way into the app. Is there something I am missing?? (I am using a custom button)

```
[PFFacebookUtils logInWithPermissions:@[@"email", @"public_profile", @"user_likes"] block:^(PFUser *user, NSError *error) {}];
```

I have this block of code being executed which gets the button to work ONLY IF the user is signed into Facebook somewhere already on the phone, excluding safari

Comment: Try adding the code that you want to occur after login to the callback rather than the segue. In the brackets, put your logic and it will call when the user logs in either from safari or the Facebook app

Comment: @PatrickBradshaw So what I have above is the callback?(I am assuming) What I am using does safari and or the Facebook app. I have a [self performSegue] method within the brackets it'll go to safari, I press okay to allow authorization and then it goes back into my app and nothing happens.

Comment: @PatrickBradshaw so now i can login through safari, I guess I was forgetting to logout which was causing an overwrite so now it works BUT I have to press the Facebook button again to log in to the app to continue the method flow. i feel like I am missing something else now

Comment: My point was that the segue call should be made: [PFFacebookUtils logInWithPermissions:@[@"email", @"public_profile", @"user_likes"] block:^(PFUser *user, NSError *error) { _HERE_ }]; which it sounds like you're doing. If you put the transition in the login block, then it should occur immediately following hitting "OK" or "CANCEL" in the Facebook screen (or simply after it redirects back to your app)